# Is it illegal to have an app that allows 2 friends to “bet” on a sporting event if money is not involved?

Tags: united-states, gambling, sport, lotteries, sweepstakes

Would it be legal in the US to have an app that allows 2 friends to “bet” on a sporting event if there is no exchange of money? Instead, the users would simply accumulate points if they win the bet? Also, there would be no notion of odds. Finally, Players could choose to “bet” on the promise of doing something, like washing the winners car.

Comment: will your app be availeable in jurisdictions that ban online gambling?

Comment: @Trish my assumption is yes. In jurisdictions where you *are* allowed to gamble with money I don't see why you wouldn't be allowed to gamble with fake points.

Comment: @Trish, yes. Ideally it would be available in all of the US.

Answer (score 1):

### Gambling is the wagering of something of value

Worthless tokens, like “points”, are not something of value so that’s not gambling. Car washing and other chores are things of value (a market for them exists) and so this is gambling.

That said, gambling is not necessarily illegal.

*Some* jurisdictions make *certain types* of gambling illegal in *certain circumstances*. For example, it’s illegal to run a [two-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-up) school outside a licensed casino, except on [Anzac Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anzac_Day) when they can be held in any licensed hotel or club.

You would need to know what laws apply to gambling where your “2 friends” are. That said, most jurisdictions are unlikely to be interested in prosecuting private wagers otherwise every elementary school child would be in jail for saying “I bet you ...”